# How to access value of textfield in controller

Tags: magento-1.8

Which procedure used for accessing text-field data in block `Edit.php` ?

```
For example:- my textfeild is in `Edit.phtml`:

     <div class="input-box">
         <input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text  <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="telephone" />
     </div>
<input type="submit" name="truemagentosubmit" value="Show Correct Address"  id="save"/>
```

my javascript function is:-

```
<script>
jQuery(document)
.ready(
        function() {

            //$('#stage').css("visibility", "hidden");

            jQuery("#save")
                    .click(
                            function() {

        var street = document.getElementById('street_1').value;
        var city=document.getElementById('city').value;
        var state=document.getElementById('region').value;      
    var zip=document.getElementById('zip').value;

       // var newcity=document.getElementById('newcity').value;
       // document.getElementById('city').value=newcity;

        var address=<?php echo $this->getcorectAdd()?>        
        var str = JSON.stringify(address);
        var newArr = JSON.parse(str);

        var CorrectZip=newArr[9];
        var CorrectStreet=newArr[0]+" "+newArr[1]+" "+newArr[4]+" "+newArr[5];
        var CorrectCity=newArr[7];
        var CorrectState=newArr[8];

        document.getElementById('correctCity').value=CorrectCity;
        document.getElementById('correctStreet').value=CorrectStreet;
        document.getElementById('correctState').value=CorrectState;
        document.getElementById('correctZip').value=CorrectZip;

        var r = confirm("CORRECT ADDRESS IS...\n"+"\nstreet="+CorrectStreet+"\ncity="+CorrectCity+"\nstate="+CorrectState+ "\nzip="+CorrectZip+"\n\nwould you like to save this address?");
       if (r == true) {
           document.getElementById('city').value=CorrectCity;
           document.getElementById('street_1').value=CorrectStreet;
           document.getElementById('region').value=CorrectState;
           document.getElementById('zip').value=CorrectZip;


    }
    // return true;



});
});
</script>
```

Before saving i need to access user entered address in textbox  to Edit.php block function getcorrectAdd() then it return correct address and then it save in database.

so,it is possible that i access textbox value in block or model before saving.without using any event.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I understood correctly, once try `$telephone = $this->getRequest()->getParam('telephone');`. You can do this once you have submitted the form.

Comment: ya sure.. even I think the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access the request at any time and get parameters, this will work in blocks, models, templates well anywhere really where you can use php.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('parameter');
```

If you are in a block that extends `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` then you can simply call `$this->getRequest()` to get the request but the model has no such function so you will have to use `Mage::app()->getRequest()`